# react-native-push-notification-ios - Missing context for method declaration

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to follow the instructions to add this package, but when I update AppDelegate.m, on the send step, the code block it specifies, creates a bunch of errors: "Missing context for method declaration"

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should put them inside "@implementation AppDelegate".

Comment: Thanks! Weird that the Github "Getting Started" instructions seem to imply the opposite.

Comment: Thanks to this, I accidentally put them after `@end`

Comment: @joffet you are right its also confused me